# Left truncation or left censoring?

Tags: survival, censoring, truncation

I am conducting a study in which I analyse the time to opt out after the free trial is ending. I have individuals who sign up for a free membership-trial period. At some point the period is ending and the hazard rate increases one month before that period, I can tell from the data. It is low before that. Therefore, I have chosen one month before end-of-trial period as my time zero. Of course, I still have data on the individuals who opted out before that, about 12%. I’m not sure whether I should call them left-censored or left-truncated though. The definition of left-censored implies that I do not know when they opted-out, but I do know that. On the other hand, the definition of truncated entails that I do not see the observations/they are hypothetical. So, neither definition fits my situation perfectly. What should I call these observations?

Comment: If you include them in the analysis as being at your time-zero they they are censored; if you exclude them then they are truncated.  If you include them with negative time, then you have the full distribution with a location shift

Comment: If all offered free trial periods are the same length, I don't see anything to lose by simply setting `time = 0` to the start of the free membership. That gets around the problem completely. If different individuals are offered different trial-period lengths, then you can include that as a predictor in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Henry: Do you if there is some websites/ressources where I can read further about includeding them with negative time? My main ressource is Klein and Moeschbergers Survival Analysis, and I don't se any mentioning about that there. Perhaps i haven't found it. EdM: Unfornunately the trial periode aren't the same length. People can be on a quite long trial period which hence that setting time = 0 to start of membership would entail that I have to consider almost all corvariates as time-dependent. Thanks for the replies both of you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's not a problem in this situation with using `onTrialPeriod` as a time-varying predictor in your model. You can keep other covariates as fixed in time if that's appropriate, just copy them over into the second data row (now with `onTrialPeriod = FALSE`) for each individual who extended beyond the trial period. That way you have at most 2 data rows for each individual. It probably makes sense to include the trial-period duration as a covariate, and to include interactions of covariates with `onTrialPeriod`. That uses all of your data most efficiently and allows for different associations of covariates with survival depending on whether the trial period is in effect.

There was a similar recent question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/604730/28500). If you don't care about the actual duration of free trial periods but only whether someone opted in, then you could use a binomial regression for the opt-in/not choice and model survival during the post-trial period.

With respect to the suggestion from @Henry in a comment, recall that a survival function in general is just 1 minus a (cumulative) probability distribution function. If the distribution function is defined for negative values then you have a survival function defined over negative values. Usual statistical survival software assumes that all time values are non-negative and will balk at using negative times, but there's no theoretical limitation on that. Left censoring is sometimes coded with `-Inf` as the start time in the counting-process data format, consistent with possible negative survival times.